# Форма обратный связи не отправляет на почту? и Пупап не работает

Tags: php, javascript

вот JS код:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      fixedContentPos: false,
      fixedBgPos: true,
      overflowY: 'auto',
      closeBtnInside: true,
      preloader: false,
      midClick: true,
      removalDelay: 300,
    }),
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
      var th = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
      }).done(function() {
        th.find(".thankyou").addClass("active");
        setTimeout(function() {
          // Done Functions
          th.find(".thankyou").removeClass("active");
          th.trigger("reset");
          $.magnificPopup.close();
        }, 3000);
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Вот mail.php

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

а вот html :

```
<form id="form__emeil">
            <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Сайт Фабрика-Окон"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="parviz19940721@gmail.com"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject"/>
            <input type="text" name="Имя" placeholder="Ваше имя..." required="required" class="men"/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="Телефон" placeholder="Ваш телефон..." class="phone"/><br/>
            <button  class="form__button" >Отправить Заявку </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 hidden__form ">
          <div class="thankyou">
            <p>Спасибо за Заявку!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Что не так?

Comment: Видимо в прошлом вашем этом же вопросе вы решили забить и не смотреть что пишет консоль а просто подождать пока кто-то посмотрит за вас? :-)

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Comment: Знаете я новичок в этом деле, по этому я стараюсь.  посмотрел на консоль Увы я Js не очень знаю

Comment: Вопрос тот же, что за ошибка при выполнении?

Comment: Смотри, у меня такое же было. В итоге это были проблемы в хостинге. Код то верный.